# How to extract multiple codes from a string and attach a score to each code? (BigQuery)

Tags: google-bigquery, extract, cumulative-sum

In Google BigQuery I need to extract where a code/multiple codes are present within a string and attach a certain score for each string/ID to output a total score.

Will attach an example of the tables I am using below:

[Shortened version of initial table I am trying to attach a total score to each ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWDmc.png)

[Shortened version of scores for each code within the initial "Exams passed" column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmPjz.png)

[Example of a query output which I am trying to produce (table 1 with extra column for "Total Score")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPYbt.png)

Any guidance on the best functions/method to code this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are different approaches, one would be:

Splitting the exams passed and making one row for each exam code of each student id. Then joining the scores table on the exam codes. Then grouping by the student id, calculating the sum of the scores.

Example with your data:

```sql
WITH exams_table AS 
(
  SELECT "9476" AS student_id, "1001:574a:2001" AS exams_passed,
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "10025", "2001"
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT "10028", "574a:191b"
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT "10256", "231A:1001"
),
scores_table AS 
(
  SELECT "1001" AS exam_code, 50 AS score,
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "2001" AS exam_code, 75 AS score,
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "191b" AS exam_code, 20 AS score,
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "231A" AS exam_code, 25 AS score,
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "574a" AS exam_code, 20 AS score
)

SELECT 
  student_id,
  STRING_AGG(exam_code, ":") AS exams_passed,
  SUM(score) AS total_score
FROM  
(
  SELECT student_id, exam_code
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      student_id, SPLIT(exams_passed, ":") AS exams_passed_split
    FROM exams_table
  ), UNNEST(exams_passed_split) AS exam_code
) LEFT JOIN scores_table USING (exam_code)
GROUP BY student_id
```